# Spinner with color background or Image using down Triangle in Android

Tags: android, android-spinner

I want to set background color or image with Spinner which shows like Dropdown and I also want down Triangle with it.
I am using Simple Spinner.
How to set this ? I am using Spinner width as `fill_parent` to make it compatible width with all devices.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize acc to ur need

bg_layer_list.xml

```
<item>
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <corners android:radius="0dp" />

        <padding
            android:bottom="5dp"
            android:left="5dp"
            android:right="5dp"
            android:top="5dp" />

        <solid android:color="#514c82" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <stroke
            android:width="2dp"
            android:color="#5f5e9a" />

        <corners android:radius="0dp" />

        <padding
            android:bottom="0dp"
            android:left="0dp"
            android:right="10dp"
            android:top="0dp" />

        <solid android:color="#403e66" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <bitmap
        android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
        android:src="@drawable/dropdown_icon" />
</item>
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <stroke
            android:width="2dp"
            android:color="@android:color/transparent" />

        <corners android:radius="0dp" />

        <padding
            android:bottom="0dp"
            android:left="0dp"
            android:right="20dp"
            android:top="0dp" />

        <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <stroke
            android:width="2dp"
            android:color="#5f5e9a" />

        <corners android:radius="0dp" />

        <padding
            android:bottom="5dp"
            android:left="1dp"
            android:right="5dp"
            android:top="5dp" />

        <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape>
        <padding android:right="20dp" />

        <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

and set the background as `android:background="@drawable/bg_layer_list"`

[image: drop down icon needed in this xml]